# How can I modify Bresenham's line algorithm to preserve order?

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, rasterizing

I have been chipping away at trying to draw a line with a mouse that adheres to a grid. I'm using Bresenhams line algorithm.

However I need it to preserve the order, so if the user is drawing to the left it will give me the points in that order.

WorldTile is a class that acts as a node on the grid.

WorldBoard is an array of WorldTiles.

```
private static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs) 
{
    T temp; 
    temp = lhs; 
    lhs = rhs; 
    rhs = temp; 
}

public static IEnumerable<WorldTile> GetWorldTilesOnLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{


    bool steep = Mathf.Abs(y1 - y0) > Mathf.Abs(x1 - x0);

    if (steep)
    { 
        Swap<int>(ref x0, ref y0); // find out how this works
        Swap<int>(ref x1, ref y1); 
    }

    if (x0 > x1)
    {
        Swap<int>(ref x0, ref x1); 
        Swap<int>(ref y0, ref y1);
    }


    int dx = (x1 - x0);
    int dy = Mathf.Abs(y1 - y0);
    int error = (dx / 2); 
    int ystep = (y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1);
    int y = y0;

    for (int x = x0; x <= x1; x++)
    {
        yield return worldBoard[(steep ? y : x), (steep ? x : y)];
        error = error - dy;
        if (error < 0)
        {
            y += ystep;
            error += dx;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Here is a version in which I tried getting it to work (it gets stuck in a while loop occasionally, quite hard to pin point why)

```
public static IEnumerable<WorldTile> GetWorldTilesOnLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    int dy = (int)(y1-y0);
    int dx = (int)(x1-x0);
    int xstep = 1;
    int ystep = 1;

    if (dy < 0) {dy = -dy; xstep = -1;}
    else {ystep = 1;}
    if (dx < 0) {dx = -dx; ystep = -1;}
    else {xstep = 1;}
    dy <<= 1;
    dx <<= 1;

    float fraction = 0;
    //Debug.Log (xstep);

    if (x0 >= 0 && x0 < worldBoard.GetLength(0) && y0 >= 0 && y0 <  worldBoard.GetLength(1))
    {
        yield return worldBoard[x0, y0];
    }

    if (dx > dy) {
        fraction = dy - (dx >> 1);

        while (Mathf.Abs(x0 - x1) > 1) {

            if (fraction >= 0) {
                y0 += ystep;
                fraction -= dx;
            }
            x0 += xstep;
            fraction += dy;
            if (x0 >= 0 && x0 < worldBoard.GetLength(0) && y0 >= 0 && y0 < worldBoard.GetLength(1))
            {
                yield return worldBoard[x0, y0];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        fraction = dx - (dy >> 1);

        while (Mathf.Abs(y0 - y1) > 1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                x0 += xstep;
                fraction -= dy;
            }
            y0 += ystep;
            fraction += dx;
            if (x0 >= 0 && x0 < worldBoard.GetLength(0) && y0 >= 0 && y0 < worldBoard.GetLength(1))
            {
                yield return worldBoard[x0, y0];
            }
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Thanks

Jim

Comment: Modifying this algorithm to draw from right to left when x0 is greater than x1 looks fairly straight-forward, but it's easier to do it when you have a context that you can use for debugging. Have you tried it and failed?

Comment: I will add my failed attempt to the question

Comment: You'll have to change the logic in the `for` loop to not use `x++` when going from right to left, and also change the sign on `ystep` when the line is _steep_.

Comment: Oh, would i somehow have it reduce x? If you have any code snippits that would help out a lot. Thanks

Comment: You're the one who has the code snippet :) -- for starters, why don't you just copy the `for` loop and then in the copy flip the direction so that it goes from `x1` to `x0` with a negative step, then add logic to use one of the `for` loops based on whether or not `x0` > `x1`. Once that works, you can look into maybe combining them back into one.

Comment: Hi. I've had another go. And updated my question, it seems to get stuck in a while loop though. If you have any suggestions as to why that would be super useful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a great deal of help from a friend here is the final solution.

WorldBoard is an array of WorldTiles.

WorldTiles are essentially nodes on a grid.

```
private static void Swap<T>(ref T lhs, ref T rhs) 
{
    T temp; 
    temp = lhs; 
    lhs = rhs; 
    rhs = temp; 
}

public static IEnumerable<WorldTile> GetWorldTilesOnLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    bool steep = Mathf.Abs(y1 - y0) > Mathf.Abs(x1 - x0);

    if (steep)
    {
        Swap<int>(ref x0, ref y0);
        Swap<int>(ref x1, ref y1);
    }

    int dx = Mathf.Abs(x1 - x0);
    int dy = Mathf.Abs(y1 - y0);
    int error = (dx / 2);
    int ystep = (y0 < y1 ? 1 : -1);
    int xstep = (x0 < x1 ? 1 : -1);
    int y = y0;

    for (int x = x0; x != (x1 + xstep); x += xstep)
    {
        yield return worldBoard[(steep ? y : x), (steep ? x : y)];
        error = error - dy;
        if (error < 0)
        {
            y += ystep;
            error += dx;
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```